# Getting Cast error from a sharedPreference method using context i made

Tags: java, android, android-studio, casting, sharedpreferences

This is the part of code in my Shared preference i get my error from:

```
package com.example.myapplication;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;

public class SharedPreferenceHelper {

    private final SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
    private final Context context;

    public SharedPreferenceHelper(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
        sharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences(this.context.getString(R.string.Profile_SharedPreferences), Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    }

    public String getName(String key) {
        switch (key) {
            case "A":
                return this.sharedPreferences.getString((this.context.getString(R.string.Profile_SharedPreferences_Name_Key_Button_A)), "");
            case "B":
                return this.sharedPreferences.getString((this.context.getString(R.string.Profile_SharedPreferences_Name_Key_Button_B)), "");
            case "C":
                return this.sharedPreferences.getString((this.context.getString(R.string.Profile_SharedPreferences_Name_Key_Button_C)), "");
            default:
                return "Error";
        }

    }
```

I Have tried to debug and i don't understand why this causes an exception error, i expect at the line :
[Debugging for looking if the key is detected?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5jhPG.png)
which matches with my key name in resources:
[resources](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YgPFx.png)

```
this.sharedPreferences.getString((this.context.getString(R.string.Profile_SharedPreferences_Name_Key_Button_A)), "");
```

to return a String value and when i go into debug mode i see the following:

```
2022-10-01 12:24:26.731  9722-9722  AndroidRuntime          com.example.myapplication            E  FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.myapplication, PID: 9722
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to java.lang.String
    at android.app.SharedPreferencesImpl.getString(SharedPreferencesImpl.java:302)
    at com.example.myapplication.SharedPreferenceHelper.getName(SharedPreferenceHelper.java:19)
    at com.example.myapplication.MainActivity.onStart(MainActivity.java:40)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1435)
    at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:8024)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleStartActivity(ActivityThread.java:3475)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.performLifecycleSequence(TransactionExecutor.java:221)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.cycleToPath(TransactionExecutor.java:201)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeLifecycleState(TransactionExecutor.java:173)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:97)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2066)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
```

also this is where i call the method from Main :

```
    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        SharedPreferenceHelper sharedPreferenceHelper = new SharedPreferenceHelper(getApplicationContext());
        eventA_Button.setText(String.valueOf(sharedPreferenceHelper.getName("A")));
}
```

Comment: Apparently, at some point in the past, you saved an integer to that `SharedPreferences` using that key. Clear your app's data, or uninstall/reinstall the app, and see if that clears up your problem.

Comment: Still crashes after i return to mainActivity page, with same error aswell.

Comment: this is how i set the names aswell in the code `editor.putString(this.context.getString(R.string.Profile_SharedPreferences_Name_Key_Button_A), name);`